# How to find the sup of $\prod_{ij}(1 - z_i\bar{z}_j)(\prod_{i}|z_i|^2)^L$

Tags: calculus, inequality

I am trying to find the maximal of $\prod_{i,j = 1}^M(1 - z_i\bar{z}_j)(\prod_{i = 1}^M|z_i|^2)^L$.

Where $z_i$ are complex numbers with $|z_i| < 1$. And $L,M$ are fixed positive integers. Things are easy for $M = 1$ or $2$, but becomes very complicated for larger $M$.

If it is not possible to find the maximal value, is it possible to give some reasonable upper bound?

Comment: 1) You should replace "maximal" in your title by "sup". 2) May I ask you what is the origin of this problem ?

Comment: Thank you for your correction. I can just say that I encountered this from a physical problem. But to write down the origin require too much background. I really believe that the answer below is correct, but I also don't know if a proof is possible.

Comment: Thanks anyway for your answer.

Answer (score 0):

This solution is incomplete but it might be still useful.

First observation: it is not immediately obvious that the number you want to maximize is real, but bear with me.

Second observation: the maximum is not unique as given a maximum $z_i^*$, you can find a continuous family of additional maxima $z_i^{*(\theta)} = z_i^* e^{i\theta}$. We use this freedom to set $z_1$ to a real and positive number.

Let us put $$z_j =r_j e^{i\phi_j}$$ with $r_i \in [0,1)$, $\phi_i \in \mathbb{R}$ and $\phi_1=0$. Plugging this parameterization into the expression, we obtain
$$f= \underbrace{\prod_{k,j=1}^M \left(1 -r_k r_j e^{ i\left(\phi_k-\phi_j \right)} \right)}_{=f_1}\underbrace{\left(\prod_{j = 1}^Mr_j^2 \right)^L}_{=f_2}.$$

Let us concentrate on the first factor. Using the replacement $k\leftrightarrow l$, we obtain
$$f_1 = \prod_{k,j=1}^M \left(1 -r_k r_j e^{ -i\left(\phi_k-\phi_j \right)} \right) = f_1^* $$
and thus the first factor is also real. In fact, we have 
$$f_1 = \left[\prod_{j=1}^M \left(1 -r_j^2\right)\right] \times  \prod_{j=1}^M  \prod_{k=j+1}^M \left(1 -r_k r_j e^{ i\left(\phi_k-\phi_j \right)} \right)\left(1 -r_k r_j e^{ -i\left(\phi_k-\phi_j \right)} \right)\\=\left[ \prod_{j=1}^M \left(1 -r_j^2\right)\right] \times \prod_{j=1}^M  \prod_{k=j+1}^M \left(1 +r_k^2 r_j^2 -2 r_k r_j \cos\left(\phi_k-\phi_j \right)  \right) >0 $$

We see that the expression is symmetry under an arbitrary permutation of $r_m$. So if the solution (with respect to $r_m$) is unique, we necessarily need to have that $r_m  = r$ $\forall m$. So let us assume this.

We then have that
$$f_1 = \left(1 -r^2\right)^M \times \prod_{j=1}^M  \prod_{k=j+1}^M \left(1 +r^4 -2 r^2 \cos\left(\phi_k-\phi_j \right)  \right) \tag{1}$$
and
$$f_2 = r^{2ML}.$$

Using $\log f = \log f_1 + \log f_2$ and the convexity of $\log$, we can convince ourselves that we may optimize $\phi_i$ to maximize $f_1$ (as the angles do not appear in $f_2$). We need to solve the equations
$$\frac{\partial \log f_1}{\partial \phi_m} = 2 r^2\sum_{j=1}^M \frac{\sin\left(\phi_m-\phi_j \right)}{1 +r^4 -2 r^2 \cos\left(\phi_m-\phi_j \right) } = 0.$$
As discussed above, we can set $\phi_1=0$. We see that $\phi_m =0$  $\forall m$ solves the problem but it is not a maximum, see (1). We obtain another solution
$$\phi_m =  \frac{2\pi (m-1)}{M} \tag{S1}$$
that corresponds to the maximum. Indeed, we have 
$$\sum_{j=1}^M \frac{r^2\sin\left(\phi_m-\phi_j \right)}{1 +r^4 -2 r^2 \cos\left(\phi_m-\phi_j \right) } = \sum_{j=1}^M \frac{r^2\sin\left(2\pi(m-j)/M \right)}{1 +r^4 -2 r^2 \cos\left(2\pi(m-j)/M \right) } =
\mathop{\rm Im}\sum_{j=1}^M \frac{1}{1- r^2 e^{2\pi i (m-j)/M}}
=0. $$

Having found $\phi_m$ in (S1), we can proceed in determining $r$. We obtain the equation
$$\frac{\partial \log f}{\partial r} =\frac{2 M L}{r} - \frac{2 M r}{1-r^2} + 4r\sum_{l=1}^M \sum_{k=l+1}^M \frac{r^2 - \cos(\phi_k-\phi_l)}{1+r^4 -2 r^2\cos(\phi_k-\phi_l)}  =\frac{2 M L}{r} - \frac{2 M r}{1-r^2} -4 \sum_{j=1}^\infty r^{2j-1} \underbrace{ \mathop{\rm Re}\left( \sum_{l=1}^M\sum_{k=l+1}^M e^{2\pi i  j(k-l)/M}\right)}_{= M(M-1)/2 \text{ if $j=0 \mod M$}; -M/2 \text{ else}}  =\frac{2 M L}{r} - \underbrace{\frac{2 M r}{1-r^2} + \frac{2 M r}{1-r^2}}_{=0}  + \frac{2 M^2 }{r(1-r^{-2M})} = 0.$$

The problem has the solution for $$ r = \sqrt[2M]{\frac{L}{L+M}}.\tag{S2}$$ Together with (S1) this seems to solve your problem.

Having found the solution with all $r_m$ equal, one can check that it is also a solution of the general case. The relevant equations are

$$ \frac{\partial \log f_1}{\partial \phi_m} = 2\sum_{j=1}^M \frac{r_m r_j \sin\left(\phi_m-\phi_j \right)}{1 +r_m^2 r_j^2 -2 r_m r_j \cos\left(\phi_m-\phi_j \right) } = 0.$$
and
$$\frac{\partial \log f}{\partial r_m}=-\frac{2 r_m}{1-r_m^2} + 2\sum_{j=1}^M \frac{r_j^2 r_m -r_j \cos(\phi_m-\phi_j)}{1 +r_m^2 r_j^2 -2 r_m r_j \cos\left(\phi_m-\phi_j \right) } = 0. $$

Comment: Thank you very much. And your result is very interesting. The maximal seems to be obtained for z_i distributing uniformly on a circle.

Comment: I believe it is the correct global maximum, but of course it might be very difficult to proof that this is indeed the case. Such problems (as you have stated) are notoriously hard. See for example [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thomson_problem).